# set focus to textbox form element following Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, asp-classic, focus

I have a number of fields on a form that I perform Validation on, which I then want to Focus on if the validation fails. The Validation works fine, i.e. rtnStr, but the focus() just won't land on any of the textbox fields, i.e. vCtrl. It remains on the Submit button.

```
<script language="javascript">

function ValidateForm() {
    var rtnStr = "";
    var vCtrl = "";

    //Contact Details //
    if (document.contactform.txtforename.value == "") {
        rtnStr = rtnStr + " - Please enter your Forename.\n"
        if (vCtrl == "") {
            vCtrl = "txtforename";
        }
    }

    if (document.contactform.txtSurname.value == "") {
        rtnStr = rtnStr + " - Please enter your Surname.\n"
        if (vCtrl == "") {
            vCtrl = "txtSurname";
        }
    }

    if (rtnStr != "") {
        alert(rtnStr)
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            document.getElementById(vCtrl).focus();
        }, 0);
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}               
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the markup?

Comment: @Samurai - Sorry, don't follow what you mean

Comment: I was asking to add your HTML form to your question, but I see you've already got an answer which worked for you, so it won't be needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that vCtrl is a string which is the **name** of a form and not the **id** which document.getElementById(vCtrl).focus() is looking for. The way to fix this is to make vCtrl store the DOM element instead of a text string.

```
<script  language="javascript">
    function ValidateForm() {
    var rtnStr = "";
    var vCtrl = "";
    //Contact Details //
    if (document.contactform.txtforename.value == "") {
        rtnStr = rtnStr + " - Please enter your Forename.\n"
        if (vCtrl == "") {
            vCtrl = document.contactform.txtforename;
        }
    }

    if (document.contactform.txtSurname.value == "") {
        rtnStr = rtnStr + " - Please enter your Surname.\n"
        if (vCtrl == "") {
            vCtrl = document.contactform.txtSurname;
        }
    }

    if (rtnStr != "") {
        alert(rtnStr)

        vCtrl.focus();

        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wrjxLud6/)